# Check DisableMSI in WiX

Tags: wix

In a setup based on http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/dialog_reference/wixui_advanced.html, I'd like to suppress option for scope (per user/per machine) based on `DisableMSI` machine policy. How can I query machine policy settings for `DisableMSI`?

Looked into querying the registry, but the key doesn't always exist;
but from the log I can see it is being checked:

```
MSI (c) (D8:CC) [timestamp]: Machine policy value 'DisableMsi' is 1
```

Comment: You should provide some context, such as where you want to check for it. If you are writing code, then this is simply a registry query to see if it's there, and retrieve its value. You can't do a search from an MSI because the MSI won't run if it's not allowed to, and if you are running maybe it's a managed install so you know its value must be 1.

Comment: Thanks @PhilDW. I'll update my query.